# Autoboxing/Unboxing while casting Integer to int using 'cast' method

Tags: java, casting, autoboxing

Here is a very simple case: I am trying to cast an Object type to a primitive like this:

```
Object object = Integer.valueOf(1234);

int result1 = int.class.cast(object); //throws ClassCastException: Cannot convert java.lang.integer to int

int result2 = (int)object; //works fine
```

This is the source code of cast method of class 'Class'

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException(cannotCastMsg(obj));
    return (T) obj;
}

private String cannotCastMsg(Object obj) {
    return "Cannot cast " + obj.getClass().getName() + " to " + getName();
}
```

Why is this happening? Same is happening with other primitives too.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/cCseuA)

Comment: Well, the documentation for `isInstance` specifies: "If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false." So it's not a surprise - but the `cast` documentation should say it will always fail for primitive types.

Comment: So I should not be using cast method for primitives, instead cast it directly using (int)?

Comment: @AnmolGupta: Yes, basically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cast` can't really work well for primitives, given that it can't return a value of the actual primitive type, due to generics in Java... so it would end up boxing again anyway. And if you're not assigning straight to an `int` value, it would have to be boxed for that reason too.

So basically, if you want to convert to `int`, just cast directly.

`isInstance` is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) to always return `false` for primitives:

> If this `Class` object represents a primitive type, this method returns `false`.

... `cast` probably should be too.