# Casting to a Generic Primitive class. Method runs without any exception, how and why?

Tags: java, generics, casting, primitive

Here is a method in which I am casting an Object to a primitive type.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T fetchPrimitive(Object object, Class<T> clazz) {    
    return (T)object;
}
```

It works fine as long as my Object is of same class as T (which is a primitive class like int, double etc.).

But, this method also runs without any exception when I provide wrong class to cast. Say if I provide the object as boolean (true/false) and clazz as int.class, then also this method runs and return (true/false) the actual Object.

I understand that Generics can not work on primitives. I just need to understand whats happening here when I am providing a primitive class as an argument and return type is Generic.

For example:

```
Object object = true;
Class clazz = int.class;

Object result = fetchPrimitive(object,clazz); 
//result = true and result.getClass() is Boolean. 
//I asked it to convert a boolean to int expecting an exception but seems that it simply ignored the casting?
```

From running the code, I understand that it's simply ignoring the casting when its a primitive class and returning whatever Object it is. I do not want it to be this way, I want it to throw an exception (ClassCastException) if wrong class is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply won't work for primitives due to the way JVM works. Since your return type is `T`, it gets erased to `Object` (as seen in Flown's answer) and even if you return a primitive it will be boxed back to `Integer`/`Boolean`/etc.

If you want the method to be able to return a primitive, it has to be specified in the return type, and there is no way for a method to return different primitives depending on the arguments. You'll have to have separate methods for each primitive, unfortunately, or live with boxing.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I wanted to confirm.. 'Since your return type is T, it gets erased to Object' is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've provided the clazz you can use `Class::cast` to get what you want:

```
public static <T> T fetchPrimitive(Object object, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(object);
}
```

If you only do a cast type erasure will transform your code into something like this:

```
public static Object fetchPrimitive(Object object, Class<Object> clazz) {
  return (Object) object;
}
```

This is absolutely valid.

Comment: Hey Flown, have a look at my previous question for problem with using cast method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052463/autoboxing-unboxing-while-casting-integer-to-int-using-cast-method/33052542#33052542

Comment: @AnmolGupta If you work with generics simply don't use primitive types. There is really no need for that.

Comment: Thanks Flown, yeah I'll refactor this piece of code. It worked for valid arguments but type erasure in case of invalid arguments is unacceptable.